# Laravel 5 Mysql duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 to insert some entries in to the database but I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'category_id' (SQL: insert into `products` (`product_name`, `product_price`, `category_id`) values (asdaszzz, 123, 1))

As I understand the problem is that the value that I want to add in the category_id table allready exist in other entry, but the thing is that the category_id table is not an UNIQUE key. Below I posted the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('product_name', 255)->unique();
        $table->decimal('product_price', 10, 4);
        $table->dateTime('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });

    Schema::table('products', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add nullable to category_id

```
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working. Why does nullable solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding table key...

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('product_name', 255)->unique();
        $table->decimal('product_price', 10, 4);
        $table->dateTime('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->index('category_id');

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```